# Subscribe to observable property within observableArray in Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, observable, subscribe, ko.observablearray

I have an observableArray of objects in my view model, and within, I have an observable property on one key:

```
var somefunc = function(sysMsgs)
{
    // Create a VO from passed array
    $.each(sysMsgs, function(i, v) {
    var tMsg = {
        ...
        READ : ko.observable(v.READ),
        ...
    };
    systemMessagesArray.push(tMsg); // Already Initialized observableArray
   });
}
```

I need to subscribe to changes on the READ key so that I can disable form controls in the view. On a regular observable, I would:

```
variable.subscribe(function(v) {do something with the value v;});
```

Any idea on how to scribe to the key within the array?
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried that ?

```
var somefunc = function (sysMsgs) {
    // Create a VO from passed array
    $.each(sysMsgs, function (i, v) {
        var tMsg = {
            READ: ko.observable(v.READ),
        };
        systemMessagesArray.push(tMsg);
        tMsg.subscribe(function {
            alert('changed');
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! The tMsg is a local var and has not been added to KO as an observable. I did try all of these variations: systemMessagesArray().subscribe(function(v) {alert('changed');}); And: systemMessagesArray().READ.subscribe(function(v) {alert('changed');}); I've also tried with out calling the array as a method (without the parenthesis) and nothing.

Comment: Could you make a fiddle to illustrate the problem ?

Comment: I wonder how memory intensive this is. It would be better if there was a way to say "sysMsgs.subscribe("tMsg", function(){ console.log("changed"); })"